# Assembler mov issue

Tags: function, begininvoke

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assembler mov issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690157/assembler-mov-issue)

I have the next code:

```
mov  ax,@data
mov  ds,ax
```

Why I can not write just like this?

```
mov ds,@data
```

All source:

```
   .MODEL small
   .STACK 100h
   .DATA
   HelloMessage DB 'Hello, world',13,10,'$'
   .CODE 
   .startup
   mov  ax,@data
   mov  ds,ax
   mov  ah,9
   mov  dx,OFFSET HelloMessage
   int  21h
   mov  ah,4ch
   int  21h
   END
```

Thank you!

Comment: This Question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690157/assembler-mov-issue

Comment: Sorry man. It is my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't move directly @data in ds because you can't assign directly a segment to ds. You are allowed to move a register with the value of the segment you want to move in ds.